# Recommendation for near real time data sync between DynamoDb and S3/Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a bunch of tables in DynamoDB (80 right now but can grow in future) and looking to sync data from these tables to either Redshift or S3 (using Glue on top of it to query using Athena) for running analytics query.

There are also very frequent updates (to existing entries) and deletes happen in the DynamoDB tables which I want to sync along with addition of newer entries.

Checked the Write capacity units (WCU) consumed for all tables and the rate is coming out to be around 35-40 WCU per second at peak times.

Solutions I considered:

1. Use Kinesis Firehose along with lambda (which reads updates from DDB streams) to push data to Redshift in small batches (Issue: it cannot support updates and deletes and is only good for adding new entries because it uses Redshift COPY command under the hood to upload data to Redshift)
2. Use Lambda (which reads updates from DDB streams) to copy data to S3 directly as json with each entry being a separate file. This can support updates and deletes if we have S3 filepath same as primary key of DynamoDB tables (Issue: It will result in tons of small files in S3 which might not scale for querying using AWS Glue)
3. Use Lambda (which reads updates from DDB streams) to update data to Redshift directly as soon as a new update happens. (Issue: Too many small writes to Redshift can cause scaling issues for Redshift as it is more suited for batch writes/updates)

Comment: Why use Redshift? Unless you're at a scale where Redshift is the only option (in which case, up-to-the-minute updates are just noise), you will probably find Postgres more than sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Could you find a solution? Have you also considered using Eventbridge?